# APFS Partition won't expand into adjacent free space under Mojave

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I tried to install Linux Mint on an external drive and the installer crashed.

I used Gparted to delete the two partitions I had created (one ExFat, the Other Ext4) and rebooted into MacOS Mojave. I then tried to add the free space to an APFS Partition name "Shared" and it would not let me.

From other answers it appears another partition is preventing it but I can't tell which one. Would someone please tell me the **EXACT** commands to enter in Single user mode (Command-S, right?) to fix it?

The output of `diskutil list` is:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         499.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data iMac Windows 10         501.0 GB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.0 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh 1TB           161.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      5.4 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *16.0 TB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Mac Backup 1            2.0 TB     disk2s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         10.2 TB    disk2s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Emergency Boot 1        501.9 GB   disk2s5
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk2s6

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +10.2 TB    disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s3
   1:                APFS Volume Shared                  1.9 TB     disk3s1
```

[image: Diskutil Drive Partition Window]

Comment: Check the actual partitioning with `diskutil list` in Terminal & add to your question.

Comment: Please add also output of `sudo gpt show disk2` This will show the actual sectors the partitions start on and so where the free space is.  You seem to be missing `disk2s4` in `diskutil list`

Comment: @lx07 Attempting to execute "get show disk2" resulted in "Suspicious MBR at sector 0" "bad map" and "unable to open disk2" appearing on consecutive lines. Does this mean I have to completely wipe the drive to repair it?

Comment: No you don't need to wipe the drive - it just means that the disk has a hybrid member for some reason.  You can delete it and create a protective member using [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) as described in this answer by the tools author without losing any data :  https://superuser.com/questions/1140907/suspicious-mbr-at-sector-0-is-there-a-way-to-fix-it (i.e. `sudo gdisk /dev/disk2` then `x` `n` `w` `y`)

Comment: Is disk2 the only disk you want to change?

Comment: @BryanDunphy Please install TeamViewer, invite me (send an email to klanomath(at)googlemail.com with the credentials) and I'll have a look...